# Escaping Lua Arguments in Freeswitch

Tags: lua, escaping, freeswitch

In Freeswitch arguments passed to lua scripts are space delimited (see http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_lua#Passing_Arguments ).

I've worked out that you can wrap the argument in single quotes, and this then ignores the space but I can't then work out how to escape single quotes.

How should arguments with spaces be passed to Lua?

To recreate the problem:

Example Lua script:

```
argumentOne=argv[1];
argumentTwo=argv[2];
argumentThree=argv[3];
argumentFour=argv[4];

freeswitch.consoleLog("info", "*******************\n");
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", argumentOne);
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", "\n");
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", argumentTwo);
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", "\n");
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", argumentThree);
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", "\n");
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", argumentFour);
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", "\n");
freeswitch.consoleLog("info", "*******************\n");
```

This works fine:

```
freeswitch@internal> luarun luaargumenttest.lua one two 'thr ee'  four
+OK

freeswitch@internal> 2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197 *******************
2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197 one2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197
2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197 two2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197
2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197 thr ee2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197
2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197 four2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197
2012-06-24 11:56:55.873757 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1197 *******************
```

But how would I send in the argument value "three's a crowd"?

I've tried \', '', ''' and also " and \" but non of these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the FreeSWITCH code, and it looks like there's no way to escape a single quote:

here mod_lua calls switch_separate_string()
https://github.com/FreeSWITCH/FreeSWITCH/blob/ee8c9e869ba0da3d4f620769c1e241be71d99e6f/src/mod/languages/mod_lua/mod_lua.cpp#L156

here switch_separate_string calls separate_string_blank_delim(), and it only catches a single quote as an argument delimiter:
https://github.com/FreeSWITCH/FreeSWITCH/blob/ee8c9e869ba0da3d4f620769c1e241be71d99e6f/src/switch_utils.c#L2062

Comment: Thanks Stanislav. I'll raise an issue in Jira and for the moment I'll hack though bu stripping single quotes from the argument value before wrapping the argument.

Comment: you can also change the workflow -- for example, catch the event in ESL and execute your code

Answer (score 1):

I tried the example and can escape a ' fine.
Is this done on latest GIT?

```
lua q.lua one two 'three\'s a crowd'  four
2012-06-24 13:52:55.376758 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1227 *******************
2012-06-24 13:52:55.376758 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1227 one
2012-06-24 13:52:55.376758 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1227 two
2012-06-24 13:52:55.376758 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1227 three's a crowd
2012-06-24 13:52:55.376758 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1227 four
2012-06-24 13:52:55.376758 [INFO] switch_cpp.cpp:1227 *******************
```